# Easiest way to override a font in Safari 11?

Tags: macos, safari, automation

In Chrome or Firefox we can use [Stylish](http://www.userstyles.org). There seems to be an unofficial [extension](http://sobolev.us/stylish/) for Safari but I’m put off by its use of Google Analytics.

In my case I am only interested in changing the font on one particular website. Specifically, I want to override the monospace font on a given website to eg, Menlo. For instance:

`@font-face {
   font-family: monospace;
   src: local('Menlo');
}`

I'd rather not use an extension for this and I do want this to apply to one particular website, so a manual toggle to globally apply a piece of CSS is the last resort I can think of.

Is there an easier way to automate this that doesn’t require installing an extension?

Comment: Easy might depend on how the one site is coded. Would you edit in some html or the site in specific you wish to make a change? It could be as simple as a small CSS modification.

Comment: Super great edit. I'll see if I can hack something together later this weekend. I don't have an obvious tool that comes to mind - this detail is excellent.

Comment: I'm guessing you know there already is a manual toggle for custom stylesheets, it's just not very convenient... Prefs > Advanced > Style Sheet.